# $\int_\ell \vec{F(x)} \cdot\vec{T(x)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate

$$ \int_\ell \vec{F}(x) \cdot\vec{T}(x)$$

Where $\vec{F} = (y^2, x, z^2)$ and $\ell : \vec{v}(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 1);~~ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

I'm not too deep into vector calculus so I'm not sure how to tackle this integral. I'm not sure if I have to use Stokes's or Gauss's Theorem. Tips are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is $\vec{T}(x)$ the derivative of $\vec{v}(t)$?  In vector calc it's extremely important to keep track of what each object is.  This problem looks just like a straight-forward line integral.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. It's how the problem is written.

Comment: What is $T (x) $?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the question is written with really confusing notation.  This looks like a straightforward line integral where $\vec{F}(x)$ is some field and $\vec{T}(x)$ is the derivative of the curve $\vec{v}(t)$.  Honestly, a better more consistent way to write this would be to write:

$$
\int_{\mathscr{l}} \vec{F}\left (\vec{v}(t)\right ) \cdot \vec{v}'(t) dt
$$

where you are taking the dot product of the field with the tangent direction, but also evaluating the field at the particular point of contact along the trajectory $\vec{v}(t)$.  Computing this isn't hard: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{v}(t) & = & \left (\cos t, \sin t, 1\right ) \\
\vec{v}'(t) & = & \left (-\sin t, \cos t, 0\right ) \\
\vec{F}\left (\vec{v}(t)\right ) & = & \left (\sin^2t, \cos t, 1 \right ).
\end{eqnarray*}

Now computing the integral we get:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathscr{l}} \vec{F}\left (\vec{v}(t)\right ) \cdot \vec{v}'(t) dt & = & \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2(t) - \sin^3(t) dt \\
& = & \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2(t)dt - \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^3(t)dt \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \left (1 + \cos(2t)\right )dt - \int_0^{2\pi} \sin (t)\left (1 - \cos^2(t)\right )dt \\
& = & \pi + \left . \left(\cos t - \frac{1}{3}\cos^3t\right ) \right |_0^{2\pi} \\
& = & \pi.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes, the notation is confusing.. I would check with my professor however he's not at the university. Thank you anyway.